# Table generated in by Javascript not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, loops, html-table

This table is not displaying in my html file: can anyone see an obvious mistake? I've been staring at it for hours!

```
<div id="data_list">
            <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("<table border='1' rules='rows' cellspacing='0'>")
    document.write("<tr>");
    document.write("<th>Date</th><th>Amount</th><th>First Name</th>");
    document.write("<th>Last Name</th><th>Address</th>");
    document.write("</tr>");

    for (i=0;i<=amount.length;i++){
        if (i%2=0){
            document.write(<tr>);
            }else{
            document.write("<tr class='yellowrow'>");
            }

        document.write("<td>" + date[i] + "</td class='amt'>" + amount[i]+ "</td>");
        document.write("<td>" +firstName[i] + "</td><td>" + lastName[i] + "</td>");
        document.write("<td>" + street[i] + "<br />" + city[i] + ", " +state[i]+ "" +  zip[i] + "</td>");
        document.write("</tr>");
}
    document.write("</table>");
    </script>
```

Comment: You're missing a semicolon at the end of line 3.

Comment: Also you should consider appending your table to a variable then calling `document.write()` once at the end of your script. It may improve performance and will make your script more flexible and appear cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
if (i%2=0){
    document.write(<tr>);
}else{
    document.write("<tr class='yellowrow'>");
}
```

should be

```
if (i%2==0){
    document.write('<tr>');
}else{
    document.write("<tr class='yellowrow'>");
}
```

`i%2=0` should be `i%2==0`
Also, `<tr>` should be a string `'<tr>'`

Comment: Thank you! that did it, Karthik my coworker? what a small world!

Comment: Oh My God ! Indeed a small world. See you tomorrow :)