# Create Table in Javascript using For Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, html-table

Hello Fellow Developers,
I am a newbie in Javascript and finding it difficult to create a table in JavaScript using For Loop. It would be great if you would help me out.

I am trying to make a Barclays premier league table using Javascript, for which i have saved data in various variables and using them as the for loop increments.

```
    var teams = ["Arsenal", "Chelsea", "Man City", "Liverpool", "Everton", "Spurs", "Newcastle", "Southampton", "Man Utd", "Aston Villa", "Swansea", "Hull", "West Brom", "Stoke", "Cariff", "Norwich", "West Ham", "Fulham", "Crystal Palace", "Sunderland"];
var played = ["14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", ];
var won = ["11", "9", "9", "8", "7", "7", "7", "6", "6", "5", "5", "5", "3", "3", "3", "4", "3", "3", "3", "2"];
var draw = ["1", "3", "1", "3", "6", "3", "2", "4", "4", "4", "3", "2", "6", "5", "5", "2", "4", "1", "1", "2"];
var lost = ["2", "2", "4", "3", "1", "4", "5", "4", "4", "5", "6", "7", "5", "6", "6", "8", "7", "10", "10", "10"];
var goalsScored = ["29", "28", "40", "30", "22", "13", "19", "18", "22", "16", "20", "12", "17", "12", "11", "12", "12", "12", "8", "11"];
var goalsAgainst = ["10", "14", "14", "17", "13", "15", "21", "13", "18", "16", "19", "18", "19", "18", "20", "28", "15", "26", "22", "28"];
var teamImages = ["Images/Teams/1.ico", "Images/Teams/2.ico", "Images/Teams/3.ico", "Images/Teams/4.ico", "Images/Teams/5.ico", "Images/Teams/6.ico", "Images/Teams/7.ico", "Images/Teams/8.ico", "Images/Teams/9.ico", "Images/Teams/10.ico", "Images/Teams/11.ico", "Images/Teams/12.ico", "Images/Teams/13.ico", "Images/Teams/14.ico", "Images/Teams/15.ico", "Images/Teams/16.ico", "Images/Teams/17.ico", "Images/Teams/18.ico", "Images/Teams/19.ico","Images/Teams/20.ico"];
```

And so far i have developed the following code...

```
var createTable = document.createElement("table");
        createTable.id = "bplTable";
        createTable.border = "1";
            var createHeaderRow = document.createElement("tr");
            createHeaderRow.id = "tableHeader";
                var th1 = document.createElement("th");
                th1.innerHTML = "Pos";
                var th2 = document.createElement("th");
                th2.innerHTML = "";
                var th3 = document.createElement("th");
                th3.innerHTML = "Team";
                th3.id = "teamName";
                var th4 = document.createElement("th");
                th4.innerHTML = "P";
                var th5 = document.createElement("th");
                th5.innerHTML = "W";
                var th6 = document.createElement("th");
                th6.innerHTML = "D";
                var th7 = document.createElement("th");
                th7.innerHTML = "L";
                var th8 = document.createElement("th");
                th8.innerHTML = "F";
                var th9 = document.createElement("th");
                th9.innerHTML = "A";
                var th10 = document.createElement("th");
                th10.innerHTML = "+/-";
                var th11 = document.createElement("th");
                th11.innerHTML = "Pts";
                createHeaderRow.appendChild(th1);
                createHeaderRow.appendChild(th2);
                createHeaderRow.appendChild(th3);
                createHeaderRow.appendChild(th4);
                createHeaderRow.appendChild(th5);
                createHeaderRow.appendChild(th6);
                createHeaderRow.appendChild(th7);
                createHeaderRow.appendChild(th8);
                createHeaderRow.appendChild(th9);
                createHeaderRow.appendChild(th10);
                createHeaderRow.appendChild(th11);    
for (i = 1; i < 21; i++)
                {
                    var createNewRow = document.createElement("tr");
                    var td1 = document.createElement("td");
                    th1.innerHTML = [i];
                    var td2 = document.createElement("td");
                    th2.innerHTML = "<img alt=&quot;" + teams[i] + "&quot; src="+teamImages[i]+"/>";
                    var td3 = document.createElement("td");
                    th3.innerHTML = teams[i];
                    th3.id = "teamName";
                    var td4 = document.createElement("td");
                    th4.innerHTML = played[i];
                    var td5 = document.createElement("td");
                    th5.innerHTML = won[i];
                    var td6 = document.createElement("td");
                    th6.innerHTML = draw[i];
                    var td7 = document.createElement("td");
                    th7.innerHTML = lost[i];
                    var td8 = document.createElement("td");
                    th8.innerHTML = goalsScored[i];
                    var td9 = document.createElement("td");
                    th9.innerHTML = goalsAgainst[i];
                    var td10 = document.createElement("td");
                    th10.innerHTML = goalsScored[i] - goalsAgainst[i];
                    var td11 = document.createElement("td");
                    th11.innerHTML = (won[i] * 3) + (draw[i]);
                    createNewRow.appendChild(td1);
                    createNewRow.appendChild(td2);
                    createNewRow.appendChild(td3);
                    createNewRow.appendChild(td4);
                    createNewRow.appendChild(td5);
                    createNewRow.appendChild(td6);
                    createNewRow.appendChild(td7);
                    createNewRow.appendChild(td8);
                    createNewRow.appendChild(td9);
                    createNewRow.appendChild(td10);
                    createNewRow.appendChild(td11);
                    createTable.appendChild(createNewRow);
                }
    createDiv.appendChild(createTable);
    getID("bodyContent").appendChild(createDiv);
```

I just get the following output

```
 20 "undefined" undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   NaN NaN
```

I tried debugging it a lot.. but in vain..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like something AngularJS ng-repeat could do. See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat

Comment: @JamesMohler we haven't been taught AngularJS yet.. i tried using JSON instead of variables first, but it wasnt allowed too.. :( 
The assignment is to use Javascript to insert the elements.. and no markups on the html page...

Comment: How about using document.write(). Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159451/table-generated-in-by-javascript-not-displaying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixing your code:

You have 20 items in the array, arrays start at 0, which means the last ID is 19. So your `for` needs to be less than 20, not 21.

Next, everything in the `for` is making `td#` vars, but you're trying to change the values of the `th#` vars.

Finally, you don't have a `createDiv` variable, which obviously keeps your table from being output.

```
var teams = ["Arsenal", "Chelsea", "Man City", "Liverpool", "Everton", "Spurs", "Newcastle", "Southampton", "Man Utd", "Aston Villa", "Swansea", "Hull", "West Brom", "Stoke", "Cariff", "Norwich", "West Ham", "Fulham", "Crystal Palace", "Sunderland"];
var played = ["14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", ];
var won = ["11", "9", "9", "8", "7", "7", "7", "6", "6", "5", "5", "5", "3", "3", "3", "4", "3", "3", "3", "2"];
var draw = ["1", "3", "1", "3", "6", "3", "2", "4", "4", "4", "3", "2", "6", "5", "5", "2", "4", "1", "1", "2"];
var lost = ["2", "2", "4", "3", "1", "4", "5", "4", "4", "5", "6", "7", "5", "6", "6", "8", "7", "10", "10", "10"];
var goalsScored = ["29", "28", "40", "30", "22", "13", "19", "18", "22", "16", "20", "12", "17", "12", "11", "12", "12", "12", "8", "11"];
var goalsAgainst = ["10", "14", "14", "17", "13", "15", "21", "13", "18", "16", "19", "18", "19", "18", "20", "28", "15", "26", "22", "28"];
var teamImages = ["Images/Teams/1.ico", "Images/Teams/2.ico", "Images/Teams/3.ico", "Images/Teams/4.ico", "Images/Teams/5.ico", "Images/Teams/6.ico", "Images/Teams/7.ico", "Images/Teams/8.ico", "Images/Teams/9.ico", "Images/Teams/10.ico", "Images/Teams/11.ico", "Images/Teams/12.ico", "Images/Teams/13.ico", "Images/Teams/14.ico", "Images/Teams/15.ico", "Images/Teams/16.ico", "Images/Teams/17.ico", "Images/Teams/18.ico", "Images/Teams/19.ico","Images/Teams/20.ico"];

var createTable = document.createElement("table");
        createTable.id = "bplTable";
        createTable.border = "1";
            var createHeaderRow = document.createElement("tr");
            createHeaderRow.id = "tableHeader";
                var th1 = document.createElement("th");
                th1.innerHTML = "Pos";
                var th2 = document.createElement("th");
                th2.innerHTML = "";
                var th3 = document.createElement("th");
                th3.innerHTML = "Team";
                th3.id = "teamName";
                var th4 = document.createElement("th");
                th4.innerHTML = "P";
                var th5 = document.createElement("th");
                th5.innerHTML = "W";
                var th6 = document.createElement("th");
                th6.innerHTML = "D";
                var th7 = document.createElement("th");
                th7.innerHTML = "L";
                var th8 = document.createElement("th");
                th8.innerHTML = "F";
                var th9 = document.createElement("th");
                th9.innerHTML = "A";
                var th10 = document.createElement("th");
                th10.innerHTML = "+/-";
                var th11 = document.createElement("th");
                th11.innerHTML = "Pts";
                createHeaderRow.appendChild(th1);
                createHeaderRow.appendChild(th2);
                createHeaderRow.appendChild(th3);
                createHeaderRow.appendChild(th4);
                createHeaderRow.appendChild(th5);
                createHeaderRow.appendChild(th6);
                createHeaderRow.appendChild(th7);
                createHeaderRow.appendChild(th8);
                createHeaderRow.appendChild(th9);
                createHeaderRow.appendChild(th10);
                createHeaderRow.appendChild(th11);    
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                {
                    var createNewRow = document.createElement("tr");
                    var td1 = document.createElement("td");
                    td1.innerHTML = [i];
                    var td2 = document.createElement("td");
                    td2.innerHTML = "<img alt=&quot;" + teams[i] + "&quot; src="+teamImages[i]+"/>";
                    var td3 = document.createElement("td");
                    td3.innerHTML = teams[i];
                    td3.id = "teamName";
                    var td4 = document.createElement("td");
                    td4.innerHTML = played[i];
                    var td5 = document.createElement("td");
                    td5.innerHTML = won[i];
                    var td6 = document.createElement("td");
                    td6.innerHTML = draw[i];
                    var td7 = document.createElement("td");
                    td7.innerHTML = lost[i];
                    var td8 = document.createElement("td");
                    td8.innerHTML = goalsScored[i];
                    var td9 = document.createElement("td");
                    td9.innerHTML = goalsAgainst[i];
                    var td10 = document.createElement("td");
                    td10.innerHTML = goalsScored[i] - goalsAgainst[i];
                    var td11 = document.createElement("td");
                    td11.innerHTML = (won[i] * 3) + (draw[i]);
                    createNewRow.appendChild(td1);
                    createNewRow.appendChild(td2);
                    createNewRow.appendChild(td3);
                    createNewRow.appendChild(td4);
                    createNewRow.appendChild(td5);
                    createNewRow.appendChild(td6);
                    createNewRow.appendChild(td7);
                    createNewRow.appendChild(td8);
                    createNewRow.appendChild(td9);
                    createNewRow.appendChild(td10);
                    createNewRow.appendChild(td11);
                    createTable.appendChild(createNewRow);
                }
    document.body.appendChild(createTable);
```

Comment: Thanks Rhyono! That helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
var teams = ["Arsenal", "Chelsea", "Man City", "Liverpool", "Everton", "Spurs", "Newcastle", "Southampton", "Man Utd", "Aston Villa", "Swansea", "Hull", "West Brom", "Stoke", "Cariff", "Norwich", "West Ham", "Fulham", "Crystal Palace", "Sunderland"];
var played = ["14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", ];
var won = ["11", "9", "9", "8", "7", "7", "7", "6", "6", "5", "5", "5", "3", "3", "3", "4", "3", "3", "3", "2"];
var draw = ["1", "3", "1", "3", "6", "3", "2", "4", "4", "4", "3", "2", "6", "5", "5", "2", "4", "1", "1", "2"];
var lost = ["2", "2", "4", "3", "1", "4", "5", "4", "4", "5", "6", "7", "5", "6", "6", "8", "7", "10", "10", "10"];
var goalsScored = ["29", "28", "40", "30", "22", "13", "19", "18", "22", "16", "20", "12", "17", "12", "11", "12", "12", "12", "8", "11"];
var goalsAgainst = ["10", "14", "14", "17", "13", "15", "21", "13", "18", "16", "19", "18", "19", "18", "20", "28", "15", "26", "22", "28"];
var teamImages = ["Images/Teams/1.ico", "Images/Teams/2.ico", "Images/Teams/3.ico", "Images/Teams/4.ico", "Images/Teams/5.ico", "Images/Teams/6.ico",'','','','','','','','','','','','','','']
var output='<table>';
for (var i=0;i<teams.length;i++)
{
output+='<tr><td>'+teams[i]+'</td><td>'+played[i]+'</td><td>'+won[i]+'</td><td>'+draw[i]+'</td><td>'+lost[i]+'</td><td>'+goalsScored[i]+'</td><td>'+goalsAgainst[i]+'</td><td>'+teamImages[i]+'</td></tr>'    
}
output+='</table>';
$('body').append(output);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NHQWV/)

Comment: I try to avoid that much string concatenation and use something like `var output=[]; output.push('<table>'); output.join('')` - here is a demo with this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/NHQWV/1/ Of course I got into this habit back when this was much faster I should see if this still helps in modern browsers

Comment: Turns out the `array.join('')` hasn't been faster than string concatenation for sometime now (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299010/why-is-string-concatenation-faster-than-array-join), If you fix your broken HTML (need to close your `<td>` and `<tr>`) then this has my vote.  Manipulating the DOM one element and one property at a time is tedious, send the browser HTML it's good at parsing that stuff.

Comment: Thanks Sridhar! That helped me understand the problem!

Answer (score 0):

First mistake that i see , your i variable for loop must start at 0 not at 1

second mistake seems to be copy/paste error , on the loop you have to use the variable name tdx not thx:

```
var td3 = document.createElement("td");
t3.innerHTML = teams[i]; //instead of th3
t3.id = "teamName";
```

and for include in your body html , i have to know about basic structure.

Otherwise use jquery framework for exemple like propose Shidhar